# insert data into database while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

.I want to insert data into database while typing values in textbox.... My ajax coding doesn't working.... Even i didn't get any errors...

Help me soon

**my ajax coding is:**

```
var userid = '#uid';
var datas = 'uid=' + $(userid).val();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uid").on("keyup", function() {
        $ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            url: "insert.jsp", //insert.jsp
            dataType: 'text',
            data: datas, //data to be sent as a parameter cname=babu&mobileno=9877&boxno=
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " HttpStatus: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + " " + errorThrown + "\n");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**My jsp code for inserting record is:**

```
  <%
String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","testing");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into insert1(usrid) values('"+uid+"')");
if(i>0){
    %>Inserted Successfully.... If you want to insert another value means then click here<a href="index.jsp">Insert</a>
    <p>Other Wise<a href="listuser.jsp">List User</a>
<%}else{%>
    The information you are entered is wrong<a href="index.jsp">Retry</a>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Wait Wait Wait. Do you need to insert single digit values or entire words? if  you need to digit entire words, I would rather call a timeout that preforms the ajax request if any key hasn't been pressed for about 2 seconds, else you're going to perform a lot of ajax requests.

Comment: sounds fraught with danger to me

Comment: I want to insert entire word....Like this i have to insert multiple values

Comment: Now i want to insert multiple records...If i press tab means it display http error

Comment: Any body here to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data object to send parameter rather than string which is a clean approach and for better readability. And get the value of input inside `keyup` function.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#uid").on("keyup",function(){
     var val = this.value; //get the input value here.
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "insert.jsp",//insert.jsp
      data:{uid : val},  //use data object to send as parameters rather than string.
      success: function (result) {
                alert(result);          

      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          alert("Error: "+textStatus +" HttpStatus: "+XMLHttpRequest.status+" "+errorThrown+"\n");                
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: make sure your path correctly points to `insert.jsp` .  I think you error lies in url: "insert.jsp",//insert.jsp

Comment: same name only....but why i didn't get error in console or any other thing....My coding doesn't call ajax function...is there any mistake in my coding while calling ajax function

Comment: no your ajax code looks fine. there must be some other error or you are not calling the ajax function properly

Comment: nice you figured it out yourself. happy coding

Comment: If i want to insert multiple columns means what i have to do....I don't want to write seperate function for each text box.

Comment: multiple columns ? not getting you here.

Comment: here i am inserting one text box value to one column....now i want to insert multiple value as one row....     For example (firstname,lastname,userid,password) these values get from different textboxes

Answer (score 2):

Move the statement inside the `keyup` event handler. This will get the typed value in the `textbox` and will send to the server by `ajax`.

```
$("#uid").on("keyup", function() {
    var datas = 'uid=' + $(userid).val(); // Move inside event handler
```

You can also use `$(this)` to get the value:

```
var datas = 'uid=' + $(this).val();
```

Comment: @ShanBagam What is the problem you're facing? Is the value posted to the server? Any error in console?

Comment: There is no error in console....When i enter the value it doesn't call ajax function....I didn't get any alert messages